# Fill array with random numbers within a specified range (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, integer

I am writing code that fills in an array the size of 10 integers with random numbers within the range of 0 to 9. The code I have works but it fills all 10 slots with the exact same random integer, is there a way to randomize the integer per array item?

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

void initialize(int arr[], int size);


int main(){


    const int SIZE = 10;
    int myList[SIZE];

    initialize(myList, SIZE);
    
    return 0;

}

void initialize(int arr[], int size){
    
    srand(time(0));

    int random = (rand() % 9);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

            arr[i] = random;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        cout<<arr[j]<< endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using exact same integer in each initialization. for loop should be like that

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        arr[i] =  (rand() % 10);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also write %10 if you want to include 9  in the range. based on the formula for random number generation.
random = (rand() % (maxValue - minValue +1) +minValue;

```
 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        arr[i] =  (rand() % 10);
     }
```